# Region Info differences between windows OS

Tags: .net, windows, cultureinfo

I had an interesting problem where QA team has reported that under pt-PT culture a large number's group separator was a space instead of a dot.  When I reviewed on my Windows 7 Pro box, the `(new CultureInfo("pt-PT")).NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` reported a dot, but under Windows 2012 R2 where web application is running the same property was reporting a space.

Has anyone seen this or aware of any authoritative info why that locale is changed?